# How to render a string in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with keys and values. I'd like to render a certain keys value in my react JSX markup like this:

```
const VALUES = {
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2",
}

const MyComponent = ({name}) => (
  VALUES[name] || ""  
)
```

but this does not work. While it is legal to render strings directly in JSX like this: `<span>A string</span>` the code above fails with an error saying "inst.render is not a function" in `_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext`.

It works if the values look like this:

```
const VALUES = {
  "key1": <span>value 1</span>,
  "key2": <span>value 2</span>,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume this is because `const MyComponent` has a signature of `() => string` and not `() => ReactElement`; This error is occuring because React is attempting to call `.render()` on the return value of your function and it can't find it, so it breaks.

Indeed, it [would appear](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) that `render()` on a component can only return `ReactElement | null | false`. Given that in a stateless component, the function itself is a `render()` function, it would logically follow that your component must have the signature `() => ReactElement | null | false`.

Comment: ah could be yes. I thought because PropTypes.node could be a string too, it would be a valid render return.